# static with (void)

Tags: ios, static, void

Here is a part of Apple code.

I don't understand the first line. Why is there a "void" with a return ?

```
// forward declaration of our utility functions
static NSUInteger _ImageCount(void);

static NSUInteger _ImageCount(void)
{
    static NSUInteger count = 0;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        count = [_ImageData() count];
    });
return count;
}
```

Comment: The first declaration is just a function prototype. The `void` part of the declaration/definition just states that there are no function *parameters*. The return type is `NSUInteger`.

Comment: You are right. I used to see "void" at the beginning of line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foo(void)` means that the function does not expect any parameter. But it does return and `NSUInteger`.

```
static NSUInteger _ImageCount(void)
^      ^          ^           ^
|      |          |           parameter list
|      |          function name
|      return type
visibility (may be referenced only from this module)
```

Comment: static NSUInteger _ImageCount is good ? Or should I add "(void)" every time there is no parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you conceived the function wrongly, since function should return "NSUInteger".

"void" is the parameter type which comes from the c/c++, which specifies the "no parameter".

**static NSUInteger _ImageCount(void);**

"NSUInteger" is the return type "void" specifies no-parameter

Comment: Yes, I inverted "void" place (in my head). It changed meaning Binyamin Sharet showed a good explanation to it like yours.